# filtering datagridview with combobox populated from same database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, combobox, filtering

This is how my code really looks and performs. I have been trying to do filtering data according to comboboxes that I fill from the database and then to show data on the datagridview. Because I'm a beginner in coding, it has been really hard to write the combobox populating codes. I really searched in internet, read most of the titles. Is there any way to do this after all selections are done and maybe with the text is written in textbox and the search button (I created) clicked according to
the selections datagridview shows.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace KPI_Tool
{
    public partial class SearchForm : Form
    {
        static SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\010495\Desktop\KPI_Tool\KPI_Tool\KPI_Store.mdf;Integrated Security=True");      

        public SearchForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
// TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'kPI_StoreDataSet1.Store' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
this.myAdapter.Fill(this.myDataSet.Store);

        }



        private void Group_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

       conn.Open();
       comboBox1.Items.Clear();
       SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
       cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT GroupN FROM Store WHERE GroupN IS NOT NULL";
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
       da.Fill(dt);

       foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
       {
           comboBox1.Items.Add(dr["GroupN"].ToString());
       }

       conn.Close();


        }

        private void Tech_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            conn.Open();

            comboBox2.Items.Clear();

            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT Tech_Area FROM Store WHERE Tech_Area IS NOT NULL";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                comboBox2.Items.Add(dr["Tech_Area"].ToString());
            }

            conn.Close();

        }

        private void Level_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn.Open();

            comboBox3.Items.Clear();

            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT LevelOf FROM Store WHERE LevelOf IS NOT NULL";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                comboBox3.Items.Add(dr["LevelOf"].ToString());
            }

            conn.Close();
        }

        private void Domain_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn.Open();

            comboBox4.Items.Clear();

            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT DomainN FROM Store WHERE DomainN IS NOT NULL";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                comboBox4.Items.Add(dr["DomainN"].ToString());
            }

            conn.Close();
        }

        private void Type_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn.Open();

            comboBox5.Items.Clear();

            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT TypeN FROM Store WHERE TypeN IS NOT NULL";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                comboBox5.Items.Add(dr["TypeN"].ToString());
            }

            conn.Close();
        }

        private void Severity_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn.Open();

            comboBox6.Items.Clear();

            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT Severity FROM Store WHERE Severity IS NOT NULL";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                comboBox6.Items.Add(dr["Severity"].ToString());
            }

            conn.Close();
        }

        private void AlertTB_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            AlertTB.Clear();
        }


        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ListB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ClearB_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
            comboBox2.SelectedIndex = -1;
            comboBox3.SelectedIndex = -1;
            comboBox4.SelectedIndex = -1;
            comboBox5.SelectedIndex = -1;
            comboBox6.SelectedIndex = -1;

            AlertTB.Clear();
            AlertTB.Text = "Write Here..";

        }


        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            conn.Open();
            myBindingSource.Filter = "GroupN= '{0}'"+comboBox1.SelectedItem.Te;
            conn.Close();
        }



        }

    }
```

Here is my User Interface. I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2013. Please explain to me with very basic sentences. I want to learn the logic, the structure behind the code.

[image: UI]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the gridview according to the text you entered in the textbox you can refer to my blog post

> http://dotnetsolutionsbyankit.blogspot.in/2013/04/filter-gridview-as-you-type-in-textbox.html

so you will get an idea how to do it.

If you face any problem let me know in comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static DataSet SQLGetData(string connectionString, string commandString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        DataTable DT = new DataTable("Table1");
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandString, connection);
            //command.CommandTimeout = 3000;
            SqlDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader();
            DS.Tables.Add(DT);
            DS.Load(read, LoadOption.PreserveChanges, DS.Tables[0]);

        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
        return DS;
    }
}

private void SetFilter()
{
    string command = "SELECT * FROM Store";

    int count = 0;

    if (comboBox1.Text != "")
    {
        command = command + " WHERE GroupN = '" + comboBox1.Text + "'";
        count = count + 1; 
    }

    if (comboBox2.Text != "")
    {
        if (count == 0)
        {
            command = command + " WHERE Tech_Area = '" + comboBox2.Text + "'";                
        }
        else
        {
            command = command + " AND Tech_Area = '" + comboBox2.Text + "'";
        } 
        count = count + 1;                 
    }

    if (comboBox3.Text != "")
    {
        if (count == 0)
        {
            command = command + " WHERE LevelOf = '" + comboBox3.Text + "'";                
        }
        else
        {
            command = command + " AND LevelOf = '" + comboBox3.Text + "'";
        }
        count = count + 1;                 
    }
    // comboBox4, comboBox5, comboBox6 

    string connStr; //Connection string;

    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    DS = SQLGetData(connStr, command);      
    DataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];               
}
```

Comment: Because data adapter can not handle string type It should be converted into Text. How can we do that?